# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <abc@myemail.com>: Relay access denied

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, smtp

Trying to send an email in a java springboot application in my local setup.

I am getting the below error even for the valid email address.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <abc@mydomain.com>: Relay access denied

    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:491)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:361)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
```

*Note :  It was successfully sending the email a day before. It started throwing the error without even changing any configuration in my application.
Is there any port setting configuration in my system that must have been changed or what could be the possible reason for this?
*